# Which tool can be used to configure the CPU priority of a process?

Tags: process, ps, top, process-management, nice

I know that you can use nice to re assign priorities of processes but which tool can be used to configure the CPU priority of a process ?

Comment: In what way does `nice` not answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try the control groups (cgroups) facility. Introduced since Linux 2.6.24, it is a very flexible tool to assign CPU shares to processes as well as to place caps on resource (blockio, network, memory) utilization for each process. Here's [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/cgroups.txt).

Answer (score -1):

Use the command "renice" to change a process priority